# Unable to close PopUp

Tags: jquery, popup

I make a jQuery dialog window to show on page scroll and display a div in this popup. The problem is if I close the popup and continue to scroll the window shows again and again. So how can I close it for good?

```
<div id="spopup" style="display: none;">
<!--close button-->
<a style="position:absolute;top:14px;right:10px;color:#555;font-size:10px;font-weight:bold;" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return closeSPopup();">
    <img src="ico-x.png" width="18" height="18"/>
</a>
```

The css:

```
#spopup{
    background:#f3f3f3;
    border-radius:9px;
    -moz-border-radius:9px;
    -webkit-border-radius:9px;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 3px #333;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 3px #333;
    box-shadow:inner 0 0 3px #333;
    padding:12px 14px 12px 14px;
    width:300px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:13px;
    right:2px;
    display:none;
    z-index:90;
}
```

The jquery

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop()>=$(document).height()/5)
        $("#spopup").show("slow");
    else 
        $("#spopup").hide("slow"); }); function closeSPopup(){

    $("#spopup").hide("slow"); 
}
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jqvo1tmf

Comment: Obviously, it will show as this `if($(document).scrollTop()>=$(document).height()/5)` condition will satify on every scroll...when you scroll down

Comment: So, what I could do?

Comment: First let us know what you want to achieve...the dialog window should only popup when your scroll reach at `$(document).height()/5`?

Comment: Check my solution below, your code might get reduced a little bit.

Comment: Solved ... after BlackBurn027 replay ... Anyway thanks all ... really grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple / quick fix for this issue would be to use a global variable which acts as a flag

Initially the flag shall be 0 / false

On start scrolling when he event triggers check if the flag was rised (wasClosed)

if not then show the pop up else keep it hidden.

The flag will be switch to true once the user clicks on the close button.

```html
<script>
var wasClosed = false;

function closeSPopup(){
    $("#spopup").hide("slow");
    wasClosed = true;
};

$(window).scroll(function(){

if($(document).scrollTop()>=$(document).height()/5 && !wasClosed)
   $("#spopup").show("slow");
else 
   $("#spopup").hide("slow");
});

</script>
```

Comment: Its working ..... Sorry everybody else ... I tried your suggestions but didn't work only BlackBurn suggestion worked!.... Thanks :*

Answer (score 2):

Your on-click function is not getting called, so instead of that you can give id to your close button image and then write close function accordingly.

Assuming id of your close image is `close`.

Then JS would be :

```
$("#close").on('click', function(){
   $("#spopup").hide("slow");
});
```

Please check fiddle for your solution [Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/jqvo1tmf/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this : [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jqvo1tmf/5/)

**Code updated -**

```
var popup ='1';
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop()>=$(document).height()/5 && popup=='1')
        $("#spopup").show("slow");else $("#spopup").hide("slow");
});
function closeSPopup(){
popup ='0';
    $("#spopup").hide("slow");
};
```

Comment: I didn't tried your code but thanks for your replay.... Solved ... after BlackBurn027 replay ...

Answer (score 0):

When you first show a popup add a class to it. Like "fired".

Then when you scroll, check if the popup has this class.

And if not, then show it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <a style="position:absolute;top:14px;right:10px;color:#555;font-size:10px;font-weight:bold;" href='#'>
    <img src="ico-x.png" onclick="closeSPopup()" width="18" height="18"/>
</a>
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if it included an explanation along with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You get the following error in your fiddle :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: closeSPopup is not defined

So you have just to put the definition of your function `closeSPopup()` in body, check the [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jqvo1tmf/1/).

Hope htis helps.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler:

```
    //$("#spopup").hide("slow");
    $("#spopup").remove();
```

Full code sample:

```
    $(window).scroll(function(){
       if($(document).scrollTop()>=$(document).height()/5)
       $("#spopup").show("slow");else $("#spopup").hide("slow");
    });
    function closeSPopup(){
      //$("#spopup").hide("slow");
      $("#spopup").remove();
    };
```